# using jq to create an array of key value pairs and iterate over them

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

Given this input...

```
[
    {
    "name": "steve",
    "description": "",
    "id": 2253,
    "accountGuid": "12345"
  },
    {
    "name": "mary",
    "description": "",
    "id": 2363,
    "accountGuid": "12345"
  },
    {
    "name": "chris",
    "description": "",
    "id": 2226,
    "accountGuid": "12345"
  }
]
```

My end goal is to take the `id` and `name` values, iterate over them and use the id in a curl and then output the result of that to a separate json file named `[name]-[id].json`

I am able to grab one value just fine using `jq -r '.[] | (.id)'` but can't add in `(.name)`.

I have tried `to_entries` but the output of that didn't assist me, at least to my understanding.

I have also tried `'.[] | "\\(.id) \\(.name)"'` - this results in an id and a name each on its own line.

Comment: Try something along the lines of `while read -r id; read -r name; do curl ... "${id}" ... > "${name}-${id}.json"; done < <(jq -r '.[] | .id, .name' file.json)`

Comment: I don't understand what you're supposed to do with your json input, but here's a `jq` suggestion : `jq -r '.[]|[.name, "https://www.somesite.org/path/\(.id)"]|join(" ")'`.  Should produce `NAME URL` on separate lines, which could be used in a Bash `read` loop ...

Comment: Or simply `jq -rc '.[]|[.name, .id]|join(" ")'` if you just want `NAME ID` in your `read` loop (building the `curl` URI separately in pure Bash).

Comment: Something like `jq -r --arg url 'http://example.com/get' '.[]|("curl --url "+($url+"?id="+(.id|@uri)|@sh)+" -o "+(.name+".json"|@sh))' | sh`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method with turning the json into a Bash associative array declaration for key and value pairs:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Populates Bash array from json
# shellcheck disable=SC2155 # Declaration safely generated by jq
declare -A names="($(jq -r '.[]|"[\(.id|@uri|@sh)]=\(.name|@sh)"' a.json))"

# Uncomment for debug
declare -p names; set -x

# Iterates names by keys
for id in "${!names[@]}"; do
  name="${names[$id]}"
  curl -s --url "https://example.com/get?id=$id" -o "${name}.json"
done
```

*Edit*: Adopted A.H.'s suggestion for string interpolation in jq.

Comment: Instead of the string concatenation the string interpolation might be a little improvement: `.[]|"[\(.id|@uri|@sh)]=\(.name|@sh)"`

Comment: The idea of using `jq` with associative arrays in the shell is nice!
I can use that immediately!